# react-query useQueryClient is not a function in Jest or QueryClient is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, next.js, react-query

Ill trying to explain this situation.
Currently my tests fails for next reason:

- First situation: **TypeError: react_query_1.useQueryClient is not a function**
- Second situation: **Type error react_query_1.QueryClient is not a constructor**

The scenario is:

I have react-query configured in a next-js project and I am running different types of tests.

in _app.js I have:

```
<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <MainAppContainer>
                 <Component {...pageProps}
            </MainAppContainer>
 </QueryClientProvider>
```

the queryClient file it's in config/client.ts

```js
import { AxiosError } from "axios";
import Router from "next/router";
import { QueryClient } from "react-query";

export const minValidityRetry = 2;

export const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
        queries: {
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
            refetchOnMount: false,
            onError: (err: AxiosError) => {
                if (err?.response?.status === 403) {
                    Router.push('/unauthorized');
                }
            }
        },
    }
});
```

I have this function that it is used in differents components:

```js
import { useQueryClient } from 'react-query';

export function useContextAni() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const profilingCached: { dataContext: IDataContext } = queryClient.getQueryData('profiling');
  const contextAniCached = profilingCached?.dataContext.ani || UserStorage.contextAni();
  
  return contextAniCached;
}
```

And I have a **mocks**/react-query/index.tsx because I need to fill this data

```js
const reactQuery = jest.requireActual('react-query');

const useQueryClient = () => ({
    getQueryData: (index) => {
        if (index === 'profiling') {
            return ({
                dataContext: {
                    ani: ''
                },
                profile: {}
            })
        }
    }
});

reactQuery.useQueryClient = useQueryClient

export default reactQuery;
```

But this it throwing **TypeError: react_query_1.QueryClient is not a constructor**

If you didn't create the __mocks __ / react-query / index.tsx to mock that object, you would have the second case: Type error react_query_1.QueryClient is not a constructor

And it would have many cases of failed tests.

An example of a test:

```js
it("Component render ok", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<RechargeResume amount={100} credit={"104"} lineRecharge={ani}/>) 
        expect(wrapper).toBeTruthy()
});
```

That component use useContextAni hook

```js
const RechargeResume = (props: {
    credit: string | string[];
    amount: number;
    type?: string | string[];
    lineRecharge?: string | string[];
}) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const ani = useContextAni();
....
```

Any help?

Comment: my advice would be to not try and mock react-query, but to render your component with a QueryClientProvider in the test with a dedicated queryClient that you only create for testing. You can also prime it with some data via setQueryData. I have a writeup with an example repo here: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/testing-react-query

Comment: Yep, I realize that. The problem was when I do not wrapped my component with a QueryProvider, so this component do not access the real class required.
I'll see your example.
Thank you